# Bootstrap 3 Form elements alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3
I have a div which contains a search form.
I want to align the select boxes in the manner, as shown in the attached image.I also need (Price Slider) or space for price slider

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chaitu11/70yLmLtj/)

[image]

```
   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Slider</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">

            <!------------------slider----------------->
             <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-199165">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-199165">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-199165">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-199165">
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/500/sports/1" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/500/sports/2" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/500/sports/3" />

                    </div>
                </div> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-199165" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> 
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-199165" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </div>
            <!------------------slider-end---------------->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

         <div class="well"> 
             <form class="form">
              <h4>Quick Search</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                <option>Propery</option>
                <option>Ketchup</option>
                <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                <option>City</option>
                <option>Ketchup</option>
                <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                <option>Area</option>
                <option>Ketchup</option>
                <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
              </div>  

                <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button">Search</button></span>
            </form>
          </div>

    </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for property search section: just add class `col-md-6` in the div with class `form-group` and for search button place the button in seperate div of class `col-md-6` and replace class `btn-sm` with `btn-block`.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="well">
    <form class="form">
         <h4>Quick Search</h4>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Your Price Slider</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Propery</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>City</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Area</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```